IK bone flips suddenly during movement
I have a simple IK setup trying to replicate a robot arm rotating a wheel on a rotating platform. I'm new to rigging and can't seem to figure out why the bones flip during movement. I've read a few posts here and one of the solution is to use poles but that hasn't worked for me. The face in the top arrow is flipping when the rig is moving. I've applied a copy location constraint to the IK controller.
File attached. 

Hello, your setup seems a bit complicated, what is your robot supposed to do and not do exactly?

I think your setup is a bit complicated and could be simplified, that said the main problem is that you haven't bent the bone chain so Blender doesn't know how to bend it when animated, just bend a bit forward like that in Edit mode (image) and create a pole target again:

